# Without using L'Hospital's rule, I want to find a limit of the following.

Tags: analysis, limits

> Given a series with $a_n = \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n$ , determine whether it converges or diverges.

The ratio test was inconclusive because the limit equaled 1.

So I tried to use the root test. So the problem was reduced to finding $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}$$

Since the book hasn't covered derivatives, yet, I am trying to solve this without using L'Hospital's rule. So the following is the strategy that I am trying to proceed with.

I cannot come up with a way to simplify the expression, so I am trying to compare $a_n$ to a sequence that converges to 1 or maybe something less. In fact, I want to compare it to 1 because of that reason.

The problem with this is that adding constants makes the series divergent, and I suspect that the series converges, so I don't think that works at all.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Try writing out the first few terms in the sum together.

Comment: If $x_n$ does not converge, the series $\sum x_{n+1}-x_n$ diverges. And conversely.

Comment: @user60338 are you talking about the series ?

Comment: @julien I'm not sure what you mean by $x_n$. If you are talking about $a_n$, then it converges so it's not really useful to me.

Comment: @hyg17 No, he means $x_n=\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_n = \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\ge\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}=b_n~(say)\\\displaystyle\sum b_n\text{ is divergent by p series test and so is } \displaystyle\sum a_n.$$

Comment: Oh, the p-series. Why didn't I think of that ? Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

Hint: what is the $n^\text{th}$ partial sum of your series?

Comment: Ah, I see. $\Sigma a_n = \sqrt{n+1}-2$ so as $n \to \infty$ it diverges. Well, that been said, how do I confirm it with the ratio test ?

Comment: Confirmation is unnecessary, the partial sum argument is decisive. Anyway, I think in the OP it is said that the Ratio Test is inconclusive (and indeed it is). The Root Test is also inconclusive.

Comment: @hyg17 To show that a series diverges, it is necessary and sufficient to show that it satisfies the _definition_ of divergence. You do not always need to quote a named theorem (_e.g._ "ratio test") to do this.  They are just there to make your life easier when it would be tedious to verify the definition directly.

Comment: @hyg17 Also, what I think you mean to say is that $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i = \sqrt{n+1}$, so as $n \to \infty$ it diverges.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: For $n\ge 0$
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} > \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}.$$

Comment: Although this works, it transforms a trivial divergence into a nontrivial one.

Comment: @julien: The $p$-series is nontrivial? I like the partial sum way too, but that answer was taken.

Comment: Yes. Comparatively, the fact that $\lim \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=+\infty$ is nontrivial, as opposed to $\lim \sqrt{n}=+\infty$. It's all relative.

Comment: @julien: I can't help but agree. :)

Comment: @hyg17: For what it's worth, though the ratio test fails the result can be obtained using a higher order ratio test, [Raabe's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html).